# Ada - aspect identifier expected

Tags: ada, gnat, ada2012

I've recently started using the gnatcoll, gnatcoll_sql, gnatcoll_postgres libraries within GNAT GPS Community Edition.

My default.gpr file looks like this..

```
with "gnatcoll";
with "gnatcoll_postgres";



project Default is

   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("main.adb");

   package Compiler is
      for Switches ("ada") use ("-gnat12");
   end Compiler;

end Default;
```

My main file looks like this

```
with gnatcoll.SQL.Postgres;  use gnatcoll.SQL.Postgres;
with gnatcoll.SQL.Exec;      use gnatcoll.SQL.Exec;
with Ada.Text_IO;            use Ada.Text_IO;


procedure Main is

begin


   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Test");



end Main;
```

When I Execute I receive the following error message...

```
gprbuild -d -P/home/parallels/Documents/Ada Projects/Connect to Database 2/default.gpr -XGNATCOLL_OS=unix -XBUILD=PROD -XXMLADA_BUILD=static -XLIBRARY_TYPE=static -XGNATCOLL_CORE_BUILD=static -XGNATCOLL_BUILD=static /home/parallels/Documents/Ada Projects/Connect to Database 2/src/main.adb
gcc -c -gnat12 main.adb
gnatcoll-sql.ads:747:12: aspect identifier expected
gnatcoll-strings_impl.ads:315:10: aspect identifier expected
gnatcoll-strings_impl.ads:318:52: aspect identifier expected
gnatcoll-strings_impl.ads:393:15: aspect identifier expected
gnatcoll-strings_impl.ads:396:51: aspect identifier expected
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
[2020-04-22 09:36:12] process exited with status 4, 6% (1/16), elapsed time: 00.75s
[2020-04-22 10:00:24] Could not locate executable on path: xterm
```

I'm dubious to attempt to alter this code, as it's within the gnatcoll library. Please can anyone advise me if I should alter the code within `gnatcoll-strings_impl.ads` & `gnatcoll-sql.ads` Or is there another solution?

I couldn't include the `gnatcoll-strings_impl.ads` & `gnatcoll-sql.ads` files below for reference, as they're too large! Here are some screen shots for reference...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Added 29/04/20

```
Builder results
    /home/parallels/gnatcoll-db/sql/gnatcoll-sql_impl.adb
        30:14 warning: license of withed unit "GNATCOLL.Utils" may be inconsistent
    /home/parallels/gnatcoll-db/sql/gnatcoll-sql_impl.ads
        30:14 warning: license of withed unit "GNATCOLL.Refcount" may be inconsistent
    /home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/include/gnatcoll/gnatcoll-atomic.ads
        38:29 "-" not declared in "Atomic_Counters"
        104:37 "=" not declared in "Atomic_Counters"
        97:33 ">" not declared in "Atomic_Counters"
        35:52 "Atomic_Unsigned" not declared in "Atomic_Counters"
```

Added 02/05/20

```
[parallels@localhost ~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[parallels@localhost ~]$ sudo yum -y install gcc
[sudo] password for parallels: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * updates: www.mirrorservice.org
Package gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[parallels@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Those error messages mean, I think, that the compiler doesn’t recognise what it’s looking at as an aspect. All that code is valid: what compiler are you actually using there? I tried it (substituting sqlite for postgres) and CE 2019 was perfectly happy.

Comment: Thank you for your responce @Simon Wright and for trying this out. I'm using the GNAT GPS Community edition compiler/IDE. Where did you substitue sqlite for postgres? Also what is CE 2019? Cheers :)

Comment: GPS is an IDE, not a compiler. CE 2019 is the 2019 Community Edition. GNAT CE *includes* GPS, the compiler, and a buch of other stuff. It’s possible to have version N of GPS run version M of the compiler. Since you’re reporting a problem with the compiler, I’m asking which version of the compiler was used. Add `-v` to the compiler switches.

Comment: I replaced postgres by sqlite in both your source files - I did this because macOS comes with sqlite and I don’t want to install a package (postgres) that I don’t use

Comment: The only compiler release I can find (from GNAT 2015 up, from FSF GCC 4.8 up) that reports `aspect identifier expected` rather than `"Foo" is not a valid aspect identifier` is FSF GCC 4.9.1 - from 2014

Comment: Thank you for your response @Simon Wright, I’m currently having issues with my Mac :( I’m waiting for the OS to arrive on a usb, until then it’s unusable. I look forward to trying your solution as soon as I am able to! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much @SimonWright I have now tried your solution and it has resolved the problem I was having. However, another error and a couple of warnings have now appeared. I have added this to my original post, as it's too long for this comment. Do you have any idea why this error is there? Thank you for your help. Lloyd

Comment: Lloyd, that should be a new question. That said, I’m puzzled that `gnatcoll-atomic` ever compiled at all; any compiler after GNAT GPL 2015/FSF GCC 5 seems to have special circuitry to recognise this apparently-illegal code. WHAT COMPILER VERSION ARE YOU ACTUALLY USING?

Comment: Hi @SimonWright, please see the updated orginal post for the compiler I am using. Thanks

Comment: There you are then. Version 4.8.5 <= version 5.

Comment: I'm currently updating to gcc (GCC) 7.3.0 0 - apparently It may take a few hours for the compilation to complete.

Comment: Thanks again @SimonWright - I owe you 'another one'!

Comment: Hey @SimonWright, the upgrade to 7.3.0 0 has now completed. When I  Build & Run within CE 2019 I recieve these errors msgs:   `Builder results
    /home/parallels/gnatcoll-db/sql/gnatcoll-sql.ads
        747:12 aspect identifier expected
    /home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2019/include/gnatcoll/gnatcoll-strings_impl.ads
        315:10 aspect identifier expected
        393:15 aspect identifier expected
        396:51 aspect identifier expected
        318:52 aspect identifier expected` If there is anything else I need to do? If so please let me know. Many thanks, Lloyd

Comment: @LloydThomas Since the problem changed twice in the course of the comments above, and then nothing more happened for a month, are you still using this question? If not, can you delete it or flag it for removal? I say this because the question's resolution isn't going to help anyone else as far as I can see.